# Programming time series relationship in graph database neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am new to neo4j. Based on recommendation, I am trying to program this table into neo4j, but I have no idea how to break down my table, or program such a relationship.

The following is my data set:

```
id    NAME      order    Duration    Lag_Time
1     FoodA     1        30          115
1     FoodB     2        30          80
1     FoodC     1        30          0
2     BunA      1        25          90
2     BunB      2        50          40
2     BunC      2        60          0
```

For each id, there will be one time series. For example, for id 1, the relationship should look as follows:

```
          FoodA        -[lag:Lag_Time]->     FoodB         -[lag:Lag_Time]->    FoodC
Property: Duration:30  Lag_Time:115          Duration:30   Lag_Time:80          Duration:30
Property: order:1                            order:2                            order:1
```

I have this large set of dataset, and I would like to do this automatically.

Comment: What labels are you planning on using for this? :Food? Also, can we assume that the order of each item for each id grouping corresponds to the single alphabetical character at the end? Using the ordering of the rows of the dataset to determine relationships, instead of it being explicit on the line, is a bit unusual, and may cause some issues if we try to IMPORT using PERIODIC COMMIT. It may be better in your case to create all the nodes first (with some extra info like Lag_Time), then after all nodes are imported form the relationships in batches.

Comment: Also it would be best to get this into CSV format, with some kind of line terminator between each element per line, like ','. Then we can use [LOAD CSV](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/load-csv/)